# laravel - if else loop not working proper

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to write an if-else loop: if there is an embed saved in the database it should display a calendar, if not it should display a button saying "add new calendar/add new embed", but it's not working. I can't figure out why. When there is an embed saved in the database it displays the embed but, if there isn't an embed it doesn't display the button to add a new calendar/embed:

Blade view:

```
@if (empty($calendars))

@else
    <h4>No calendar settings</h4><br>
    <a href="{{ route('calendarsettings.create')}}">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
            <span class="bold">Add embed</span>
        </button>
    </a>
@endif
@foreach($calendars as $calendar)
    {{ $calendar->embed }}
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function kalendarz() {
    $calendars = Calendar::with('users')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('kalendarz',['calendars'=>$calendars]);
}
```

Comment: Blade code block tells that "if there is no calendars do nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4, I would probably use the `@unless` blade directive, that will show the block, unless a condition is met. What the following code would acheive is "show the entries if we have some, and show the button unless we have some entries".

```
@if($calendar)
    // show entries
@endif

@unless(empty($calendars))
    // show a button to add a new one
@endunless
```

It kind of is the same "logic" as with an else, but somehow I think it's more clear and easy to read than an `@else` statement, and make it separate from the if.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
@if(empty($calendars))
    <h4>No calendar settings</h4></br>
    <a href="{{ route('calendarsettings.create')}}">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" type="button"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> <span class="bold">Add embed</span></button>
    </a>
@else
    @foreach($calendars as $calendar)
        {{ $calendar->embed }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: still nothing if there's no calendar. In database embed is text field

Comment: @tomczas please show result of `{{ dd($calendars) }}`

Comment: it displays nothing

Comment: that's how database to store embed look like `Schema::create('calendar', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
          $table->string('embed');
          $table->timestamps();
      });

      Schema::table('calendar', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });`

Comment: any ideas? @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Nothing wrong with your blade template, it seems calendars is empty

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` functions empty the variable `$calendars`, so try using `count()`

```
@if(count($calendars) > 0)
    <h4>No calendar settings</h4></br>
    <a href="{{ route('calendarsettings.create')}}">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" type="button"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> <span class="bold">Add embed</span></button>
    </a>
@else
    @foreach($calendars as $calendar)
        {{ $calendar->embed }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Eloquent` to get results from a database you get an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. To check if that collection is empty you use `$collection->isEmpty()` or `$collection->isNotEmpty()` (L5.4).

```
@if ($calendars->isNotEmpty())
    // Have entries.
@else
<h4>No calendar settings</h4></br>
<a href="{{ route('calendarsettings.create')}}"><button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" type="button"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> <span class="bold">Add embed</span>
   </button></a>
@endif

@foreach($calendars as $calendar)
    {{$calendar->embed}}
@endforeach
```